# Spring with class.forname()

Tags: java, spring

If an application is managed by the Spring container, can a developer still use `class.forName()` to create an instance of a particular class? Or will that violate the Spring container and result in some exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use it. The resulting object will not be managed by Spring, however.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the quick reply. Would you be able to provide some example?? Also, what if I want this new object to be managed by spring container?

Comment: Hi Tapas, Thanks for the code. Would you be able to show the code which uses class.forname as well which invokes spring bean??

Comment: @Mike object not managed by Spring means that it will not be automatically wired and proxied and it will not be available to other Spring beans. Other way to say it is that dependency injection will not occur on this object. You can find example of creating object in many places. For example, http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing a web-application and assuming you have beans defined in `applicationContext.xml` then you can use:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());        
AnyBean anyBean = (AnyBean) applicationContext.getBean("anyBean");
```

where `anyBean` is the id of the bean defined in that xml. Though it will not create a new instance rather it will return an instance.

Also you can create bean programmatically and can register to the context:

```
GenericWebApplicationContext context = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
RootBeanDefinition anyBean = new RootBeanDefinition(AnyBean.class);
context.registerBeanDefinition("anyBean",anyBean);
```

Hope this will give the answer to your question. Thanks.