# Using class.forname but want to autowire members of the target class

Tags: java, spring

I have this requirement,

My framework is in a way that it reads the class name from the configuration file as a string and I would like to use methods inside that class.

Obvious solution is to use reflection,
I have used reflection and able to call methods I wanted, but the problem is the variables inside the target class are not autowired. I understand I am not letting spring to autowire the fields by using reflection ([Spring with class.forname()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543620/spring-with-class-forname)).

Is there a way for me to autowire the class variables instead of creating new instance? Or Am I in a deadlock situation?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910997/how-to-autowire-a-dynamic-class) says I am probably at dead end. I have to use either reflection or inject the target class but not both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**: If you have access to the current Spring `ApplicationContext`, you could do this as follows:

```
String className = <load class name from configuration>
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);

ApplicationContext applicationContext = <obtain Spring ApplicationContext>
applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
```

This of course means that the class whose instance you wish to load is a Spring managed bean.  Here is a concrete example:

```
package org.example.beans;

@Component
class Foo { ... }

@Component
class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException
    CONTEXT = context;
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(String className) {
    return CONTEXT.getBean(Class.forName(className));
  }
}
```

---

**Option 2**: You could manually create an instance of the required class and then ask Spring to populate its dependencies.

This again requires access to the `ApplicationContext`.  For example:

```
T object = Class.forName(className).newInstance();

applicationContext..getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(object);
```

Comment: Option 2 worked like a charm :-)
Thank you Manish :)

I have autowired applicationContext which had all the bean and try to autowire the bean for which I have created a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Have a look at how Spring's JUnit test integration does it. That's in the spring-test module.

The runner is `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, but the actual injection code is in `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies`. It uses a Spring context that implements `AutowriteCapableBeanFactory`.

The code to do this looks like below. Note that this assumes that you have used annotations to indicate which fields need to be autowired.

```
Object bean = ...;
AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = ...;
beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(bean, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO, false);
beanFactory.initializeBean(bean, "beanName");
```