# Class.forName("name") by Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm starting to use the Spring framework and I wanted to ask a question.
There is some mechanism in Spring that allows you to create a class
via a string without using `Class.forname(String className)` ?

Comment: see this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237062/using-class-forname-but-want-to-autowire-members-of-the-target-class

Comment: Thank you. I had already seen this post. But other people have told me that there is another way to do this but I can not find it.